# Screen suddenly flashes, becomes grainy and shows visual artifacts

Tags: 14.04, graphics, visual-artifacts

While working in Ubuntu the screen suddenly flashes and becomes grainy. After logging out and then logging back in the screen "retains". This problem is mainly found when working with Inkscape and GIMP.

[image]

Comment: Does the word "retains" mean the screen retains the same artifacts even after logging back in or does it mean that it doesn't?

Comment: Please [edit] and post your graphics card or chip, amount and type of RAM, CPU, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The repeating pattern of geometric visual artifacts looks like something that could be caused by a bad memory chip in a graphics card, but please ignore this answer if your computer does not have a graphics card. If you ever get repeating audio loops and a frozen screen together when playing an online video, that confirms it. If I saw this on my desktop computer, I would try temporarily removing the graphics card or swapping it with another graphics card.

For more information visit this webpage: [Diagnose video card problems by comparing with example corrupted screens](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html)

Comment: If the computer has an integrated graphics chipset it's using part of the main RAM and the problem can be the same. This can be caused also by overheating.

Comment: Similar but not exactly the same, because malfunctioning system RAM can also cause additional non-graphical problems like skipped files when copying many files to another hard drive, whereas malfunctioning graphics card RAM causes visual artifacts when running graphics intensive applications.

Comment: Indeed and we don't know whether or not those issues occur, the OP may not be aware of other problems. The mention of Inkscape and GIMP as "triggers" actually suggests the problems occur only when certain (high) memory addresses are used and/or certain CPU resources are requested causing overheating.