# Laptop with Ubuntu keeps crashing, but it doesn't happen with windows 10

Tags: crash

Basically the screen freezes and a last sound loops. The same happens with windows 7 for some reason. Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu or just check the computer?

Well I can't really do anything with the laptop after it freezes like that, I can't use the mouse nor the keyboard. Freezes happen at a random times but most commonly when there is a YouTube video playing in a firefox browser. This laptop uses the newest ubuntu but it says that there is no available drivers for current graphics card so I guess it uses pre installed open source drivers but I don't really know. Ubuntu was installed from usb boot drive but i also have installed Ubuntu on my pc from the same drive and everything is working fine. The graphics card is Nvidia gforce gt 335m 1gb.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You have to add more details to your question. When do you get the freeze? Do you do anything specific when it freezes? Do you have mouse movement? What is your system's configuration? What version of Ubuntu do you use? What graphics card drivers, if you have a graphics card? You see, many more information is needed for your question to be answerable. Please [edit] the question to add all relevant info. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Screen artifacts problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920316/screen-artifacts-problem)